# Controller to View: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple class called ForumController that will eventually be used allover my website with quite a few methods in it. For now there is two:

```
class ForumController extends BaseController { 

    // Parses XML feed to JSON
    public static function parseXML($xml) {
        $file = file_get_contents($xml);
        $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $file);
        $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
        $simpleXML = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
        $json = json_encode($simpleXML);

        return $json;

    }

    public static function getForums($xml){
        $feed = parseXML($xml);
        return $feed;
    }

}
```

I'l be using this in views, so I learned that I can call this in an IoC container? So I made an IoC.php and included that in bootstrap.php file.

IoC.php:

```
<?php 

    View::composer('getForums', 'ForumController');
```

Now I'd like to call this in my views like so..

```
{{ ForumController::getForums('http://someForum.com/forum/syndication.php?fid=4,140,22,62,134&limit=5'); }}
```

But, as usual, I did something wrong. Error:

```
Call to undefined function parseXML()
```

This is my first time trying to use another controller besides HomeController so I'm sure I did everything wrong. How do I get the results I want?

Comment: Try with `self::parseXML()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `parseXML()` as a class method instead of a function.  In this case, using `self` or `static` (won't make any difference when you're calling it from the same class it is defined in, however if `parseXML()` is ever inherited, `static` will bind it to the class at run-time.

```
public static function getForums($xml){
    $feed = self::parseXML($xml); // or static::parseXML($xml)
    return $feed;
}
```